# Count specific value in pandas rolling window

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe with thousands rows. One column consists of only 3 values: -1, 0, 1. I would like to count in rolling window (let's say 100) how many times a specific value (let's say 0) occurs.

How can I do it? I do not see such a method related to the object Rolling and I don't know how to do it by apply.

Comment: Here is one way to do it: iterate rows and set up a counter list and a counter = 0, when the index of the df reach every 100, append to the list, and set counter to 0. As far gettting the value(I am guessing it is in a string in df), may have to use regex, or split them to a list with the help of apply(lambda x: x.split(',')) then check if 0 in the list.

Comment: What kind of index does it have? Please include `df['thecolumn'].head(7)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, I coded up a quick demo. You should get the idea.

**Example**

```py
# Parameters
# iterable - column
# size - window size (100)

def window(iterable, size=2):
    i = iter(iterable)
    win = []
    for e in range(0, size):
        win.append(next(i))
    yield win
    for e in i:
        win = win[1:] + [e]
        yield win

# Sample data
a = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]

from collections import Counter

result = []
value = 1 # Value to keep count (-1, 0, 1)

for i in window(a, 2):
    count = Counter(i)[value]
    result.append(count)

# Sample output
print(result)
[1, 0, 0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will help. I tested this, It works

```
def cnt(x):
     prev_count = 0
     for i in x:
         if i == 0:
             prev_count+=1
     return prev_count

df['col'].rolling(100,min_periods=1).apply(cnt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Pandas' [where()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and [rolling().count()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.count.html):

```
df['countcol'] = df.inputcol.where(df.inputcol == 0).rolling(100, min_periods=1).count()
```

`where` returns NaNs when the criteria isn't matched, and `count` counts all non-NaN values.